# UIViewController's weird UIView frames on rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, frame

I've encountered a problem that drove me crazy. I've solved it, but my understanding of the matter is just not enough. 
I've looked through documentation, but i guess i picked wrong topics, because didn't find the explanation.

I was assigning new center for a subview each time the VC rotates, so the `subview` always remains centered.

I am using the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for changing the UI on rotations.
When we have a VC, not embedded neither in `UINavController` nor `UITabBar`, on rotations we get the following frames:

```
portrait
{{0, 20}, {768, 1004}} 

land left
{{20, 0}, {748, 1024}} 

upside down
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} 

land right
{{0, 0}, {748, 1024}}
```

Well, seriously? The device is landscape, and my size is 748 1024??? (i understand its 748 and not 768, because of the status bar.)
But why its not 1024 748?

When I put background color - all view gets colored, as if it where 1024 748. But when i set the center to the subview, it's somewhere left-bottom, exactly in the center of a rect that is 748 1024...

I've felt like a huge idiot that knows nothing about development (I develop for iOS for 2 years), and felt that I am the most idiotic and stupid programmer ever. 
I was shocked, why I never encountered this problem? 
I've checked my old projects - set some NSlogs, and everything was fine. Then why in my new projects, and the latest one, it keeps me showing this weird information?

Then I noticed - UINavController.

I embedded the VC into a UINavCon...
Here are the logs:

```
land left
{{0, 0}, {1024, 704}} 

upside down
{{0, 0}, {768, 960}} 

land right
{{0, 0}, {1024, 704}} 

portrait
{{0, 0}, {768, 960}}
```

yes, all rotating VCs in my old projects where in `UINavControllers`... That's why...

But please, my fellow colleagues, hit me with a link, help me get the enlightenment regarding this topic. Why the frames without `UINavController` are so weird, that i cant arrange the `subviews`, and why being in a `UINavController` makes it behave as expected? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: and a secondary question: what to do in the case when I don't want/can't add the UINavController, so the view will be a subview of an another VC's view?